# Reading date time values from excel in R

Tags: r, read.csv

I have a column in following format,

```
5/26/2015 11:45
5/26/2015 12:00
5/26/2015 12:15
5/26/2015 12:30
5/26/2015 12:45
```

When I read using `read.csv` in R, it reads as follows,

```
42155.76
42155.77
42155.78
42155.79
42155.8
```

What is the problem? How to read in same format?

Comment: Can you show the code used?

Comment: It looks like the value stored in you CSV are actually numeric values that are recognized as dates.  Excel interprets dates as the number of days since 1 January 1900.  I would guess that while you see "5/26/2015 11:45", if you opened the file in a text editor, you would see "42155.76"  As we see in Pierre's answer though, the number isn't matching up with the date.  There is something else happening that we haven't accounted for, and I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: My comment assumes that you are viewing the CSV in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

```
as.POSIXct(x*86400, origin="1900-01-01")
[1] "2015-06-02 14:14:24 EDT" "2015-06-02 14:28:47 EDT"
[3] "2015-06-02 14:43:12 EDT" "2015-06-02 14:57:36 EDT"
[5] "2015-06-02 15:12:00 EDT"
```

When you view the file in Excel or similar program it shows you the arranged and formatted date, but saves it internally as days since January 1, 1900. That is what is getting saved in the csv file.

Also note that the origin date may be different than the standard. From R documentation on `?as.Date`

> Most systems record dates internally as the number of days since some
>   origin, but this is fraught with problems,...The only safe procedure
>   is to check the other systems values for known dates: reports on the
>   Internet (including R-help) are more often wrong than right.

And,

> Excel is said to use 1900-01-01 as day 1 (Windows default) or 
>   1904-01-01 as day 0 (Mac default), but this is complicated by Excel 
>   incorrectly treating 1900 as a leap year. 
>   So for dates (post-1901) from Windows Excel  as.Date(35981, origin = "1899-12-30") # 1998-07-05

**Data**

```
x <- c(42155.76,42155.77,42155.78,42155.79,42155.8)
```

Comment: The dates returned by this conversion are also different than those in the original data.  They are off by a full week.

Comment: @Benjamin The OP may not have copied the original data correctly.

Comment: Hopefully we'll hear back on this.  That difference had me stumped.

Comment: I am sorry..It was my mistake to copy the data incorrectly

Comment: `5/26/2015 11:45 42150.49`
`5/26/2015 12:00 42150.5`
`5/26/2015 12:15 42150.51`
`5/26/2015 12:30 42150.52`
`5/26/2015 12:45 42150.53`
`5/26/2015 13:00 42150.54`
`5/26/2015 13:15 42150.55`
`5/26/2015 13:30 42150.56`
`5/26/2015 13:45 42150.57`
`5/26/2015 14:00 42150.58`
`5/26/2015 14:15 42150.59`
`5/26/2015 14:30 42150.6`This is the actual data

Comment: Thank u @PierreLafortune..but even after using the POSIXct function the conversion is incorrect.I guess there is some issue with the timezone

Comment: `as.POSIXct(x*86400, origin="1899-12-30", tz="utc")`

Comment: It will get you close but not exact to the minute. Your numbers are rounded to two digits.